# SPCalendarview Sharepoint 2010 Javascript to change de date does not working

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I´ve developed a custom calendar that list some apointments from a SQLDB using LINQ.
In Sharepoint WSS 3.0 its work fine but now my company has migrate to Foundation 2010 and after install de solution and open the especified page with the webpart i've notice that links to change the month and other functions its not working.

And the itens are not been showed. In the sourcecode of the page i can see the value set on codebehind but not on the brownser.

There is just fill docs about SPCalendarview and no one talk about this

thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by user443503 looks like it has part of the answer.  Looks like the new SPCalendarView has an EnableV4Rendering property that is True by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is a defect. The workaround is to inherit your web part from Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart not System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.

Details can be found here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/f10155d3-8ac6-4d8c-8c33-b4d5dbae6e2d/